# Matplotlib ax.fill_between not showing

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I created a matplotlib plot with x-data being DateTimes.

I want to shade certain areas of the chart, like the entire chart area between 7 and 10 am.
I attempted to do something similar below, shading the entire area right of some value.

I am not getting any errors, but my chart is not showing any shading.

Could you please assist?

```
df = pd.read_csv(path)
df['DateTime2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'])
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime']).dt.time   

sns.set_palette('muted')

x = df['DateTime2']#.values

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 6))
fig.patch.set_facecolor('grey')

ax1.plot(x, df[[col for col in df.columns if 'level' in col]])
ax1.set_xlabel('Time of day')
ax1.set_ylabel('Dam level (%)')
ax1.set_ylim([0, 100])

ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.plot(x, df[[col for col in df.columns if 'status' in col]])
ax2.set_ylabel('Pump status')
ax2.yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(integer=True))

ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.HourLocator())
ax1.xaxis.set_minor_locator(mdates.MinuteLocator(byminute=30))
ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M'))
fig.autofmt_xdate(rotation=90)
ax1.set_xlim((min(x),max(x)))

y = df[[col for col in df.columns if 'level' in col]]
x2 = pd.to_numeric(x.values)
x2_mask = np.ma.masked_greater_equal(x2, 990002640000000000).mask
ax1.fill_between(x2, 0, 100, where=x2_mask, facecolor='red')

ax1.grid(which='major', alpha=0.5)
ax1.grid(which='minor', alpha=0.25)
ax2.grid(which='major', alpha=0.5)
#ax1.minorticks_on()

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
fig.savefig('output.png')
plt.close('all')
```

---

Current output:
[image]

Expected output:
Something like:
[image]
But with the red behind the lines
Paint skills for the win!

---

Script: https://hastebin.com/oyegaceneq.py

Data: https://hastebin.com/enabiguxan.csv (save as csv)

Comment: Could you show pics of the expected vs. actual charts you are getting? If you upload them, I will turn the links into images for you.

Comment: Thanks. Will edit

Comment: @ScottBoston. Yup, and make sure to set a reasonable z-order or plot the red stuff first.

Comment: @ScottBoston script: https://hastebin.com/oyegaceneq.py. Data: https://hastebin.com/enabiguxan.csv (save as csv)

Comment: The problem is entirely independent on your actual data. Why do you annoy us with it? Create a [mcve] with fake data, such that it is runnable and reproduces the problem. Once that is done, you will receive an answer within minutes.

Comment: I just finished creating a new example, but Scott beat me to it with an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this with `axvspan`:

```
ax2.axvspan('2001-05-16 07:00:00','2001-05-16 10:00:00',alpha=.5,color='red')
ax2.axvspan('2001-05-16 16:00:00','2001-05-16 20:00:00',alpha=.5,color='red')
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly like that!